# Making a placeholder plugin for Unity .Net4.5 issue

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have a C# UWP .NET4.5 plugin which I imported to Unity. But in order to use the Unity Editor with it, I must create an identical placeholder .NET3.5 plugin, which has the dummy implentation.

In my .NET4.5 plugin, this code is present:

```
    public void OnFrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args) {}
```

In order to make that function available in .NET3.5, I somehow need to replace the "MediaFrameReader" parameter to something that .NET3.5 can recognize. How should I do this?

**Things I have tried**

1. Just remove the parameters
2. Remove the entire function

None of above worked... obviously.

For more info: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-plugins.html

Comment: What is specific to MediaFrameReader that 3.5 can't recognize?

Comment: Things like Async<Task>, MediaFrameReader are part of .Net4.5 framework, so if I change the target platform to .Net3.5, I end up with a "it has a dependency on .NET Framework assembly "Version 4.000" and more.